# dropping columns by condition where dtypes are string and numeric

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data (# of columns can vary):

```
    NAME    ID  POTENTIAL_VOTERS    VOTES   SPOILT_VOTES    LEGAL_VOTES אמת ג   ודעם    ז   ... נץ  ע   פה  ף   ףץ  קנ  קץ  רק  שס  voter_turnout
0   תל אביב - יפו   5000    403338  263205  1860    261345  89567   2628    8488    9   ... 34  132 30241   105 124 2667    2906    209 10189   0.647955
1   ירושלים 3000    385888  258879  3593    255286  24696   53948   3148    10  ... 54  215 10752   37  148 1619    18330   121 30579   0.661555
2   חיפה    4000    243274  151318  1758    149560  37805   4894    12363   24  ... 16  103 16826   40  87  1596    1648    142 3342    0.614780
3   ראשון לציון 8300    195958  138998  1188    137810  31492   924 86  8   ... 16  5   19953   26  68  1821    2258    121 4095    0.703263
4   פתח תקווה   7900    177367  125633  1223    124410  22103   4810    85  8   ... 14  9   14661   15  65  1224    3227    74  6946    0.701427
5   אשדוד   70  170193  115145  1942    113203  9694    11132   33  7   ... 14  10  8841    26  74  1322    4180    80  11923   0.665145
6   נתניה   7400    168914  106738  1270    105468  14575   2921    65  5   ... 14  9   11035   40  63  1089    3177    103 8319    0.624389
```

When I try to remove columns by condition of sum (where the total sum is less than 40000 I don't need this column), using this code:

```
df.drop([col for col, val in df.sum().iteritems() if val < 40000], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

I assume this is because some of the columns are not integers (as the have text). Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: have you tried `int(val) < ...` ?

Comment: i tried now, and got this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Comment: do you need remove string columns or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need remove only numeric columns by condition:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,100005,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[10111,30000,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A       B  C      D  E  F
0  a       4  7  10111  5  a
1  b       5  8  30000  3  a
2  c       4  9      5  6  a
3  d  100005  4      7  9  b
4  e       5  2      1  2  b
5  f       4  3      0  4  b

k = 40000
a = df.loc[:, pd.to_numeric(df.sum(), errors='coerce').fillna(k + 1) > k]
print (a)
   A       B      D  F
0  a       4  10111  a
1  b       5  30000  a
2  c       4      5  a
3  d  100005      7  b
4  e       5      1  b
5  f       4      0  b
```

**Detail**:

First convert summed `Series` [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for replace not parseable strings columns to `NaN`s:

```
print (pd.to_numeric(df.sum(), errors='coerce'))
A         NaN
B    100027.0
C        33.0
D     40124.0
E        29.0
F         NaN
dtype: float64
```

And then replace `NaN`s by value + 1 which need filter for including non numeric columns:

```
print (pd.to_numeric(df.sum(), errors='coerce').fillna(k + 1))
A     40001.0
B    100027.0
C        33.0
D     40124.0
E        29.0
F     40001.0
dtype: float64
```

Last compare:

```
print (pd.to_numeric(df.sum(), errors='coerce').fillna(k + 1) > k)
A     True
B     True
C    False
D     True
E    False
F     True
dtype: bool
```

And filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df.loc[:, pd.to_numeric(df.sum(), errors='coerce').fillna(k + 1) > k])
   A       B      D  F
0  a       4  10111  a
1  b       5  30000  a
2  c       4      5  a
3  d  100005      7  b
4  e       5      1  b
5  f       4      0  b
```

### ---

Alternative solution with omiting `string`s columns and then added `True`s to mask by `reindex`:

```
df = df.loc[:, (df.sum(numeric_only=True) > 40000).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=True)]
print (df)
   A       B      D  F
0  a       4  10111  a
1  b       5  30000  a
2  c       4      5  a
3  d  100005      7  b
4  e       5      1  b
5  f       4      0  b
```

**Detail**:

First sum only numeric columns by parameter `numeric_only=True`:

```
print (df.sum(numeric_only=True))
B    100027
C        33
D     40124
E        29
dtype: int64
```

Compare by `40000`

```
print (df.sum(numeric_only=True) > 40000)
B     True
C    False
D     True
E    False
dtype: bool
```

Add `string`s columns by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
print ((df.sum(numeric_only=True) > 40000).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=True))
A     True
B     True
C    False
D     True
E    False
F     True
dtype: bool
```

Last filtering:

```
print (df.loc[:, (df.sum(numeric_only=True) > 40000).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=True)])
   A       B      D  F
0  a       4  10111  a
1  b       5  30000  a
2  c       4      5  a
3  d  100005      7  b
4  e       5      1  b
5  f       4      0  b
```

Comment: this will be quite inefficient as you are computing in every column; select_dtypes is a much better way of doing this

Comment: @Jeff - Thank you, I add alternative solution `df.loc[:, (df.sum(numeric_only=True) > 40000).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=True)]`

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `sum` will concatenate all the strings, you need to filter the df to select just the numeric dtypes and then filter them:

```
In[27]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('abcd'), 'b':np.random.randn(4), 'c':np.arange(4)})
df

Out[27]: 
   a         b  c
0  a -0.053771  0
1  b  0.124416  1
2  c -2.024073  2
3  d -2.541324  3
```

We can select just the numeric types using [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html#pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes) and pass `np.number`

```
In[28]:
df1 = df.select_dtypes([np.number])
df1

Out[28]: 
          b  c
0 -0.053771  0
1  0.124416  1
2 -2.024073  2
3 -2.541324  3
```

Now we can filter the columns:

```
In[29]:
df1.loc[:,df1.sum() > 1]

Out[29]: 
   c
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

You can see that `sum` is returning the strings concatenated

```
In[30]:
df.sum()

Out[30]: 
a       abcd
b   -4.49475
c          6
dtype: object
```

Comment: for some reason this didn't work well with my data, but your answer explained me the steps. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`sum` has a parameter `numeric_only` that you can make use of.

```
df.drop(
   [col for col, greater in (df.sum(numeric_only=True) > 40000).to_dict().items() 
    if greater is False], axis=1, inplace=True
)
```